# Json file as parameter in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: selenium, jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I am facing an issue where I want my testing suites to be controlled during runtime based on a parameter selected.
My jenkins file has parameters as below.

```
choice(choices: 'google.com\flights.google.com\nbooks.google.com',name: 'TestSite',description: 'Which site you want to build and test?')
```

Now based on selection of TestSite, I want my Json file to be populated on second parameter which has test suites names.

```
"google": {
    "all": "./spec/**/**.spec.js"
  },
  "books": {
    "all": "./spec/**/**.spec.js",
    "account": "./spec/account/**.spec.js"
  }
```

Can someone please suggest if they are able to achieve this in Jenkins pipeline? Basically populating a parameter during run time after selection of another parameter?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in Jenkins. Parameters are 'post processed', which is why an initial build is required for the Job to even realise there are parameters that require inputs. That is to say, the code in parameters is executed once the build is running, not when you load the params page. What you see in the params page is actually the result of the code in the previous job/execution.

In order to achieve this, you could have the 1st choice as the parameter and then execute the build and put in an `input` step that then evaluates the param supplied and provides more options to the user.